# How to return appropriate header for Tire search results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If you go to www.leapfm.com and make a search for lets say "Dubstep" it will return all of the dubstep songs. However, the header is still listed as "Top songs"

I'd like it to instead change to something like Search results for "Dubstep" 5 when a search is made.

I tried a hacky solution like this but it didn't work

```
<% if Tire.search.results %>
<h6>Search results:</h6>
<% else %>
<h6>Top ranked songs</h6>
<% end %>
```

Any ideas?

I'm using [this gem](https://github.com/karmi/tire)

and

[Here's the documentation](http://karmi.github.io/tire/)

The problem is more or less making the "Top songs" header change, and the search results returning in the index makes it difficult.

Comment: Is `Tire.search.results` an array?  Does `.empty?` not work on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple check against the parameters could work:

```
<% if params[:query].present? %>
  <h6>Search results:</h6>
<% else %>
  <h6>Top ranked songs</h6>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @Apane101, Dylan wrote `params[:q]` because `:q` is a common used param for search query, you can say `:q` is an alias or shortname for `:query`, I edited his answer only because I have access to your app code and I know that you use `:query` and not `:q` as params. Not all answers on SO are copy/paste ready, and some of them works better then a copy/paste ready solution, you just need to use it properly.

Comment: I looked at his site and saw it was `:query`, just a brain fart while typing it in over here :)